# GSSException: No credential found for: 1.2.840.113554.1.2.2 when trying to authenticate with kerberos ticket

Tags: python, jenkins, kerberos

I am trying to authenticate to a Jenkins instance that is configured to use Kerberos SSO using Python requests_negotiate.  The authentication is failing with the stack trace reported below appearing on the server side.

`klist` confirms that I have a valid ticket. I can successfully authenticate using cURL 7.59.0 with a build that has the GSS-API Kerberos SPNEGO features enabled:

```
curl --negotiate --user : -k --verbose https://myjenkins.example.com/
```

I also tried `requests_gssapi.HTTPSPNEGOAuth()` but got the same failure as with `requests_negotiate`.

Any suggestions for debugging this gratefully received.  This is unfamiliar territory for me.

My Python code:

```
import requests
import requests_negotiate

auth = requests_negotiate.HTTPNegotiateAuth()
response = requests.get('https://myjenkins.example.com', auth=auth, verify=False)
print (response.content)
```

The stack trace that appears on the server:

```
GSSException: No credential found for: 1.2.840.113554.1.2.2 usage: Accept
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSCredentialImpl.getElement(GSSCredentialImpl.java:600)
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:317)
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:285)
    at org.codelibs.spnego.SpnegoAuthenticator.doSpnegoAuth(SpnegoAuthenticator.java:443)
    at org.codelibs.spnego.SpnegoAuthenticator.authenticate(SpnegoAuthenticator.java:281)
    at com.sonymobile.jenkins.plugins.kerberossso.ioc.SpnegoKerberosAuthenticationFactory$SpnegoKerberosAuthenticator.authenticate(SpnegoKerberosAuthenticationFactory.java:89)
Caused: java.io.IOException
    at com.sonymobile.jenkins.plugins.kerberossso.ioc.SpnegoKerberosAuthenticationFactory$SpnegoKerberosAuthenticator.authenticate(SpnegoKerberosAuthenticationFactory.java:91)
    at com.sonymobile.jenkins.plugins.kerberossso.KerberosSSOFilter.doFilter(KerberosSSOFilter.java:182)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:132)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:232)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:209)
    at net.bull.javamelody.PluginMonitoringFilter.doFilter(PluginMonitoringFilter.java:88)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.monitoring.HudsonMonitoringFilter.doFilter(HudsonMonitoringFilter.java:113)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:132)
    at jenkins.metrics.impl.MetricsFilter.doFilter(MetricsFilter.java:125)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:132)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
    at hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:51)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at jenkins.security.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:117)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:135)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at jenkins.security.BasicHeaderProcessor.doFilter(BasicHeaderProcessor.java:92)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
    at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:67)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:90)
    at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:553)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544)
    at winstone.BoundedExecutorService$1.run(BoundedExecutorService.java:77)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Jenkins: 2.60.3
requests: 2.20.0
requests-negotiate: 1.5

Comment: My debugging suggestion is, run curl with --verbose, and compare the raw requests/headers with what you're getting with requests. If that doesn't reveal anything, you could try using python-gssapi or something similar to create the Authorization token manually - here's a code sample of how you can do that: https://github.com/pythongssapi/python-gssapi/issues/166

Comment: I have the same issue. it seems very similar to this curl bug https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=839142 - so I suspect a bug in the requests spnego code sending a bad ticket

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error working with the npm kerberos package and I solved it by explicitly demanding the SPNEGO protocol, as the error message states that credentials for this protocol are missing from the Kerberos ticket. You say it works for you with curl and SPNEGO, but neither with requests_negotiate.HTTPNegotiateAuth() nor with requests_gssapi.HTTPSPNEGOAuth(). I cannot see from the documentation or source code which mechanism requests_negotiate uses, so I would stick to requests_gssapi for now, which also makes extensive use of logging. Which log messages do you get from that one?

I feel like this is more of a comment, but I don't have the reputation to comment.